# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm working on the CIFAR10 dataset and got the following error- TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index. When I'm visualizing my predicted image it
gives me the aforementioned error. I've tried other people's solutions but it didn't work and I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated

Here's my code:

```
class_names = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']
class_names = np.array(class_names)

train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5, 5 ,i+1)
    plt.imshow(train_images[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.xlabel(class_names[train_labels[i]])
plt.show()

cnn = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=34, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),

    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])

cnn.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)

def plot_image(i, predictions_array, true_label, img):
    true_label, img = true_label[i], img[i]
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])

    plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.binary)

    predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions_array)
    if predicted_label == true_label:
        color = 'blue'
    else:
        color = 'red'

    plt.xlabel("{} {:2.0f}% ({})".format(class_names[predicted_label],
                            100*np.max(predictions_array),
                            class_names[true_label]),
                            color=color)

def plot_value_array(i, predictions_array, true_label):
    true_label = true_label[i]
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.xticks(range(10))
    plt.yticks([])
    thisplot = plt.bar(range(10), predictions_array, color="#777777")
    plt.ylim([0, 1])
    predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions_array)

    thisplot[predicted_label].set_color('red')
    thisplot[true_label].set_color('blue')

probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential([cnn, tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])

predictions = probability_model.predict(test_images)

num_rows = 5
num_cols = 3
num_images = num_rows*num_cols
plt.figure(figsize=(2*2*num_cols, 2*num_rows))
for i in range(num_images):
    plt.subplot(num_rows, 2*num_cols, 2*i+1)
    plot_image(i, predictions[i], test_labels, test_images)
    plt.subplot(num_rows, 2*num_cols, 2*i+2)
    plot_value_array(i, predictions[i], test_labels)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-f3e05a180ae8> in <module>()
  7   plot_image(i, predictions[i], test_labels, test_images)
  8   plt.subplot(num_rows, 2*num_cols, 2*i+2)
  ----> 9   plot_value_array(i, predictions[i], test_labels)
 10 plt.tight_layout()
 11 plt.show()

<ipython-input-25-ad6b0beba933> in plot_value_array(i, predictions_array, true_label)
 28 
 29   thisplot[predicted_label].set_color('red')
 ---> 30   thisplot[true_label].set_color('blue')

 TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred due to `train_labels` and `test_labels` are `2D array`.

```
train_labels
```

Output:

```
array([[6],
       [9],
       [9],
       ...,
       [9],
       [1],
       [1]], dtype=uint8)
```

You need to `flatten` these arrays into `1D array` before of training the model.

Flattening `train_labels`:

```
import numpy as np
train_labels=np.ravel(train_labels)
train_labels
```

Output:

```
array([6, 9, 9, ..., 9, 1, 1], dtype=uint8)
```

Flattening `test_labels`:

```
test_labels=np.ravel(test_labels)
test_labels
```

Output:

```
array([3, 8, 8, ..., 5, 1, 7], dtype=uint8)
```